# how to Redirect to another Action with json data in play-framework

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have the following code:

```
case class ResetPasswordJsonValidation (id : String ,email : String)

object ResetPasswordJsonValidation {

  implicit val resetPasswordRead : Reads[ResetPasswordJsonValidation]= (
    (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
    (JsPath \ "id").read(id)
  )(ResetPasswordJsonValidation.apply _)

}
```

With the following `Action`:

```
def resetPassword = Action { request =>
    request.body.asJson.get.validate[ResetPasswordJsonValidation].fold(
        resetPassword => {
            log.info("id is {}", resetPassword.id)
            log.info("email id is {}", resetPassword.email)
        }
    )
}
```

And routes file:

```
POST    /direct-user/reset-password    controllers.DirectUserController.resetPassword
```

This is the `curl` file which I use to fire a request to the route above:

```
contentType="Content-type: application/json";

data='{  "id" : "54d3732d-d728-40d3-ae63-b18ab6be8e70" ,
       "email":"bob@example.com"}';
echo "    "
echo "------------------   Sending Data   ------------------"
echo "    "
echo "Content-Type : " $contentType
echo "Data : " $data


echo "    "
echo "------------------     Response     ------------------" 
echo "    "
echo "    "
```

And the `curl` command:

```
curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json"  --data "$data" http://localhost:9000//direct-user/reset-password
```

What I want to do is have another action that redirects to `resetPassword`, but keeping the body. How to do that?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? The result password is just logging the parameters. Are you just trying to log information?

Answer (score 1):

Use flash scope

```
def A = Action {
    var email:String="bob@example.com"
    var id:String="54d3732d-d728-40d3-ae63-b18ab6be8e70"
    Redirect(routes.DirectUserController.resetPassword()).flashing(
        "email" -> email,
        "id" -> id
    )  
  }
```

The documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaSessionFlash

You will need to write the special code to get variables from the flash scope, like

```
request.flash.get("email")
```

Comment: is there anyother way of doing this as well ?

Comment: You can use get parameters, or you can use `TemporaryRedirect` (`307`). In the case of a temporary redirect, you will need to send that data from the client, you would not be able to add them in the action.